# Jest/Enzyme - Cannot call a class as a function

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

I am migrating a large application from Karma/Mocha to Jest for testing. I set up some really basic tests for our homepage components, but when I run them I get the same `TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function` error. Example of simple component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Intro extends Component {
    render() {
        const intro = 'this is a test message'

        return (
            <div>
                <p>
                    { intro }
                </p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Super basic test:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import Intro from 'Intro'

it('renders without crashing', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    ReactDOM.render(<Intro />, div)
})
```

This test gives the aforementioned `TypeError`. I believe the issue is related to how Jest is integrated with Babel/Webpack (v1.12.9), but I cannot figure out what the issue is specifically. Here's my `babel.rc`:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react", "stage-0"],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime", "add-module-exports", "transform-decorators-legacy", "transform-flow-strip-types"]
}
```

Also wondering if maybe it's an issue with Babel peer dependencies? Here's some relevant parts from my `package.json`:

```
"babel-core": "^6.3.17",
"babel-eslint": "^5.0.0-beta6",
"babel-jest": "^21.2.0",
"babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
"babel-plugin-add-module-exports": "^0.1.1",
"babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
"babel-plugin-transform-flow-strip-types": "^6.22.0",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react-hmre": "^1.0.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
"babel-register": "^6.3.13",
"babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
"jest": "^22.0.1",
"jest-cli": "^22.0.0",
"jest-enzyme": "^4.0.1"
```

Any ideas what is causing this? Can share more code if necessary.

EDIT: Here's my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleFileExtensions: ['js', 'jsx'],
    moduleDirectories: ['node_modules'],
    moduleNameMapper: {
        Intro: '<rootDir>/src/components/Home/Intro.jsx',
        styles: '<rootDir>/src/styles/index.js'
    },
    roots: ['<rootDir>/tests/'],
    verbose: true
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a relative path to `Intro`?

Comment: Yes. I have amended my question with my `jest.config.js` file and how I'm using `moduleNameWrapper`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the issue was with the way I had `moduleNameMapper` set up. I changed my folder structure by including the test files in their initial directory rather than creating a new tests folder. I also moved my Jest config to `package.json` and made some small changes there. Now I'm getting failing tests but in ways that I expected.